# How do I pass pandoc_options as output_options to rmarkdown::render()

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I have an `Rmd` file that renders into `html` correctly almost all of the time.  However, it does not render correctly when `pandoc` (used in the rendering process) finds 4 spaces in the `html` and at that point, interprets that I want to render a `markdown` code snippet instead of `html`.

I have been told that I can turn off the `markdown_in_html_blocks` feature by doing something like this:
 `pandoc -f markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks`.

I have tried calling `pandoc` directly rather than it being called implicitly by

`rmarkdown::render()`

but couldn't get that syntax to work and being able to specify this option `(-markdown_in_html_blocks)` directly as I call `render()` is preferred.  Here is the latest of I have tried without success:

Base case: works but `HTML` output file is malformed / has a code block instead of the data that I want to display in the table.

```
render("reports/Pacing.Rmd")
```

Attempted fix: not working

```
rmdFmt <- rmarkdown_format("-markdown_in_html_blocks")
pandocOpts <- pandoc_options(to = "html", from = rmdFmt)
render("reports/Pacing.Rmd",output_format = "html_document",output_file = NULL, output_dir = NULL, output_options = pandocOpts)
```

Error message: Error in (function (toc = FALSE, toc_depth = 3, toc_float = FALSE, number_sections = FALSE,  : 
  argument 1 matches multiple formal arguments

I have tried other syntax to express that I want to turn off markdown_in_html_blocks but no luck.

Comment: have you checked that `pandocOpts` is of type `list`?

Answer (score 2):

Given the following document `test.Rmd`...

```
---
title: Test
output: html_document
---

<table>
<tr>
<td>*one*</td>
<td>[a link](https://google.com)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

...you can disable the `markdown_in_html_blocks` extension via

```r
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd",
                  output_options = list(md_extensions = "-markdown_in_html_blocks"))
```

`md_extensions` is one of the arguments that can be passed to `rmarkdown::html_document` (see `?rmarkdown::html_document` for other arguments).

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be an open issue, but a simpler way to turn off/on such a feature is to directly update the YAML in Rmd file. This should work in your case:

```
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: [
      "-f", "markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks"
    ]
```